# Pre-processor directive to detect iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, c-preprocessor

I declare some constants in a header file which need to be different depending on whether it is an iPad or an iPhone app. How would I do this?

i.e.

```
#ifdef ISIPAD
static NSString myconst = @"ipad!";
#else
static NSString myconst = @"iphone!";
#endif
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159951/is-there-a-specific-xcode-compiler-flag-that-gets-set-when-compiling-for-ipad

Comment: Thanks, although the marked answer isnt quite what i wanted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're writing an universal app, you can't do a compile time check since the compiler generates one executable for both the iPhone and the iPad. If you've got separate apps for iPhone and iPad (with a shared codebase), why not just #define ISIPAD appropriately yourself. Otherwise, you have to do a check at runtime.

You could make them global variables that get initialized when your app starts up by checking to see which device you're running on then setting them appropriately.