# How does conditionally coding for iPhone and iPad work in reality?

Tags: objective-c, ios, conditional-statements, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

UIImagePicker must be presented differently on iPhone and iPad. On the iPad, it throws an exception saying this:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'On iPad, UIImagePickerController must
>   be presented via UIPopoverController'

So I must add code to my universal app which is iPad specific. What is a safe way to do it so that the app won't crash on devices which lack a UIPopoverController?

Example:

```
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0) 
                                 inView:self.view
               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                               animated:YES];
```

Also, in case I need a UIPopoverController, I need an instance variable that holds it. How would I handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check to see if a class exists by doing this.

```
Class popoverClass = (NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController"));
if (popoverClass != nil) {
// you're on ipad
} else {
// you're on iphone/ipod touch
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question looks like a dup of:
[Is there a specific Xcode compiler flag that gets set when compiling for iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159951/is-there-a-specific-xcode-compiler-flag-that-gets-set-when-compiling-for-ipad)

Answer (score 2):

You can do a quick check of which device you are on with:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
```

Comment: The `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` macro in the UIDevice header is probably a more appropriate test.

Comment: This is more straight to the point: 
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)